# Regex to select newlines in between quotation marks

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string in Ruby that resembles the following:

```
{
  "a boolean": true,
  "multiline": "
my
multiline
value
",
  "a normal key": "a normal value"
}
```

I would like to match only the newline characters in the substring:

```
"
my
multiline
value
",
```

This is so that I can replace them with escaped newline characters. The aim here is to make the JSON easier to work with in the long run.

Comment: If you only pass the substring to the regex, just use `\n`.

Comment: You say JSON, but that’s not valid JSON. And if it’s supposed to be JSON then don’t use regex; use a JSON parser.

Comment: I understand what I've provided isn't valid JSON, because my intention is to take my current JSON and transform it into something similar to that. Also I am not only passing the substring to the regex, I'm passing the entirety of the string to the regex.

Comment: Why don't you just replace all `\n` characters by `\\n` to escape the new lines ?

Comment: What's the flavor/language?

Comment: @Seblor Replacing all newlines would replace newlines outside of strings which would make the file invalid.

Comment: @SamWhan The language is Ruby

Comment: @faissaloo It's best to add information requested in comments in your question itself, since most answerers are unlikely to read comments.  I've edited your information into the question.  Cheers!

Comment: I'll note that this is generally a *parsing* problem, not a regex problem.  If your string has any escaped quotation marks (e.g. "foo \" \n\"bar\": \"baz\"") almost any proposed regex solution is going to fail.  I'd suggest you change to an approach that *parses* the JSON, then write the JSON back out in the format you desire.

Comment: I understand, but JSON parsing is often expensive, especially when working with large pieces of JSON in a dynamic language like Ruby, hence why I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Is it really `"a normal value"` by itself—a key with no value—between curly braces, as you have it written? Or is that a transcription error?

Comment: @mwp Transcription error

Comment: @faissaloo Okay, what's it supposed to be? Would you please update your question?

Comment: @mwp I've fixed it

Comment: What about using yaml to load the string, get a hash and then its values? `require 'yaml'; YAML.load(str).values.select { |value| value =~ /(?=^\s).*(?=\s$)/ }`

Comment: @SebastianPalma At that point it's simpler for me to just extract the value with a regex and then replace the newlines (which is what I'm doing in the absence of a pure regex solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPdate*** - These regex work as expected.
From @faissaloo - `it seemed to fail however on my large` [JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/homes-england/monitor-api/cf1e536340ab63aaa1b00f8af9254c8032719c1d/lib/ui/gateway/schemas/hif_return.json).
I ran this large string using both regex:
 PCRE  https://regex101.com/r/3jtqea/1
 Ruby   https://regex101.com/r/1HVCCC/1
They both work identically, and without flaw.
If you have any other concerns, please let me know.

---

I think Ruby supports the Perl like constructs.
If so, it can be done in a single global find and replace.
Like this:

***Edit***  - Ruby doesn't do Backtracking Control Verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`
so, to do this in Ruby code, requires the regex to be more explicit.
So, with a slight modification of the pcre/perl regex, the Ruby equivalent is:

***Ruby***
Find

```
(?-m)((?!\A)\G|(?:(?>[^"]*"[^"\r\n]*"[^"]*))*")([^"\r\n]*)\K\r?\n(?=[^"]*")((?:[^"\r\n]*"(?:(?>[^"]*"[^"\r\n]*"))*[^"]*)?)
```

Replace

```
\\n\3
```

https://regex101.com/r/BaqjEE/1
https://rextester.com/NVFD38349

Explained ( but it's complex )

```
 (?-m)                                    # Non-multiline mode safety check
 (                                        # (1 start), Prefix. Capture for debug
      (?! \A )                                 # Not BOS
      \G                                       # Test where last match left off

   |                                         # or, 
      (?:                                      # Optionally align to next " ( only used once )
           (?> [^"]* " [^"\r\n]* " [^"]* )
      )*

      "                                        # A new quote to test
 )                                        # (1 end)

 ( [^"\r\n]* )                            # (2), Line break Preamble. Capture for debug
 \K                                       # Exclude from the match (group 0) up to this point

 \r? \n                                   # Line break to escape

 (?= [^"]* " )                            # Validate we have " closure

 (                                        # (3 start), Optional end quote and alignment.
                                               # To be written back.
      (?:
           [^"\r\n]* "                   
           (?:                                      # Optionally align to next "
                (?> [^"]* " [^"\r\n]* " )
           )*
           [^"]* 
      )?
 )                                        # (3 end)


 # Ruby Code:
 #----------------------
 # #ruby 2.3.1 
 # 
 # re = /(?-m)((?!\A)\G|(?:(?>[^"]*"[^"\r\n]*"[^"]*))*")([^"\r\n]*)\K\r?\n(?=[^"]*")((?:[^"\r\n]*"(?:(?>[^"]*"[^"\r\n]*"))*[^"]*)?)/
 # str = '{
 #   "a boolean": true,
 #   "a boolean": true,
 #   "a boolean": true,
 #   "a boolean": true,
 #   "multiline": "
 # my
 # multiline
 # value
 # asdf"
 # ,
 # 
 # "a multiline boo
 # lean": true,
 # "a normal key": "a multiline
 # 
 # value"
 # }'
 # subst = '\\n\3'
 # 
 # result = str.gsub(re, subst)
 # 
 # # Print the result of the substitution
 # puts result
```

---

***For Pcre/Perl***
Find

```
(?:((?:(?>[^"]*"[^"\n]*"[^"]*))+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"|(?!^)\G)([^"\n]*)\K\n(?=[^"]*")((?:[^"\n]*")?))
```

Replace

```
\\n$3
```

https://regex101.com/r/06naae/1

Explained ( but it's complex )
Note if you're on a windows box where editors need CRLF breaks,
add a `\r` in front of the LF, like this `\r\n`.

```
 (?:
      (                             # (1 start), Prefix capture, for debug
           (?:
                (?> [^"]* " [^"\n]* " [^"]* )
           )+
           (*SKIP) (*FAIL)               # Consume false positives, but ignore them
                                         # (need this to align next ")
        |                              # or,
           "                             # A new quote to test
        |                              # or, 
           (?! ^ )                       # Not BOS
           \G                            # Test where last match left off
      )                             # (1 end)

      ( [^"\n]* )                   # (2), Preamble capture, for debug
      \K                            # Exclude from the match (group 0) up to this point
      \n                            # Line break to escape
      (?= [^"]* " )                 # Validate we have " closure
      (                             # (3 start), End quote, to be written back
           (?: [^"\n]* " )?
      )                             # (3 end)
 )
```

Comment: This crashes in Ruby with the error: target of repeat operator is not specified

Comment: @faissaloo - Yeah, looks like Ruby doesn't like the backtracking control verbs. You could always resolve the issue with a gsub call back. Or, you could just use Perl or PCRE engines to do the job. I recommend that you try that and leave Ruby alone, unless you're a strong programmer.

Comment: @faissaloo - Did you try the Ruby regex ?

Comment: Yes, it seemed to fail however on my large JSON but I'm not exactly sure why. I may accept your answer soon nonetheless since it does the one I specified in my question and seems to work in most cases.

Comment: @faissaloo - Post the large JSON text somewhere, I'll look at it with my tools I don't like my regex not working %100 across the board.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/homes-england/monitor-api/cf1e536340ab63aaa1b00f8af9254c8032719c1d/lib/ui/gateway/schemas/hif_return.json

Comment: @faissaloo - I updated my answer with some new test cases using your large JSON string. Both regex work as expected...

Comment: I feel like the issue stems from some sort of peculiarity when it comes to the escaping of some parts of the regex, nonetheless I've accepted your answer

Comment: @faissaloo - The Ruby regex matches the entire string. Here are some helpful hints:  At this site, https://regex101.com/settings turn off (uncheck) _Wrap long lines_.  Also, you should always check for balanced (evenness of ) quotes before running these regex's.
You can do that with this regex:  `^[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$`  https://regex101.com/r/iusyC6/1

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you. You capture the `\n` inside the string and then can replace it:

```
"[^"]*(\n)*",
```

[Test it](https://regexr.com/4b6n6)

Comment: This just selects the string

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be something like this:

```
string = '{
  "a boolean": true,
  "multiline": "my
multiline
value",
  "a normal value"
}'

puts string.match(/"(\w+)(\n+\w*)+"/).to_s.gsub!("\n", '\n')
```

This matches the regex in your string and then substitutes the newlines with escaped newlines.

Comment: I'm currently doing something similar as an interim solution

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can use a regex like:

```
'"(?=\n).*?"'
```

---

**Matches:**

```
"
    my
        multiline
    value
        ",
```

---

**Demo:**

1. [Regex Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fhvZw5/w2)

Answer (score 0):

If your multiline strings don't include commas (right before the line breaks) then you could use that in json every line has to end with `,`, `{`, or `[` or the next line has to start with `}` or `]`:

```
json_string.gsub(/(?<!,|\{|\[)\n(?!\s*[}\]])/, '\n')
```

If you have commas in your strings (or curly and square brackets) you can improve this approach by adding more details to the list of valid line endings:

```
valid_line_ends = %w(true, false, ", }, ], { [)
line_end_matcher = valid_line_ends.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join('|')
json_string.gsub(/(?<!#{line_end_matcher})\n(?!\s*[}\]])/, '\n')
```